# Find the p-value for group of data using apply function in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics

I have a data set as follows:

```
salary_old<-c(100,200,300,400,10000,100,10,20,30)
salary_new<-c(200,300,400,500,230,240,30,40,50)
d<-as.Date(c('2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03'))
country<-c('USA','UK','IR')
id<-c('A','B','A')
data<-data.frame(id,country,d,salary_new,salary_old)
data<-data %>% arrange(id,country,d)
```

Then I want to calculate the T.test for the salary old and new for each group using loop or apply function to check if the p-value of each group is less than 0.05.

I wrote codes as follows:

```
z<-by(data,data$id,apply(data[,4:5],2,function(x,y){
  t.test(x,y)
}))
```

could you please give me some advice. 
This the error that I got:

```
 Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

I want the output will be like the follows:

```
id   country  p-value
A     USA      0.9
A     IR       0.9
B     UK       0.34
```

Comment: Off-topic here. Please see advice in the Help Center about software-specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't grasp your code very well but I can give you an easier way.

First Make a list of the factors you want to iterate on with `split()`, then use `lapply()`

```
datlist <- split(data , data$id)

lapply(
  X = dat2 ,
  FUN = function(x) {
    t.test(datlist$A[["salary_new"]] , datlist$B[["salary_old"]])
  }
)
```

results

```
$`A`

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  dat2$A[["salary_new"]] and dat2$B[["salary_old"]]
t = 0.40138, df = 3.5973, p-value = 0.7108
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -270.1249  356.7916
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 276.6667  233.3333 


$B

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  dat2$A[["salary_new"]] and dat2$B[["salary_old"]]
t = 0.40138, df = 3.5973, p-value = 0.7108
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -270.1249  356.7916
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 276.6667  233.3333
```

you can store the output in a list variable and slice to a p-values only

Edit

Enter your full data to get the results

```
 salary_old<-c(100,200,300,400,10000,100,10,20,30)
salary_new<-c(200,300,400,500,230,240,30,40,50)
d<-as.Date(c('2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03'))
country<-c('USA','UK','IR')
id<-c('A','B','A')
data<-data.frame(id,country,d,salary_new,salary_old)
data<-data %>% arrange(id,country,d)

datlist <- split(data ,list(data$id , data$country) )


results<-  lapply(
  1:length(datlist) ,
  FUN = function(x) {
    t.test(datlist[[c(x,4)]] , datlist[[c(x,5)]])
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks I have modified the question and show how I want to see out put, could you please give an advice.

Comment: I think you are not giving me the full data, right?

Comment: yes I put only sample data

Comment: I wrote this line of code but it gives me an error: data1<-data %>% group_by(id,country,d) %>% mutate(test=t.test(salary_old,salary_new))

Comment: I have modified the data frame , I want to have t.test apply for each country for all dates in a group

Comment: I error I got from this code is because some categories has no observations. This solution is not valid anyway because you are trying to group by and you have different numeric variables

Comment: Could you please let me know what is the solution

Comment: See the edit. I don't have time to extract p-value from the result list, I may comeback later

Comment: I just ran the code but it shows the following error:Error in t.test.default(datlist[[c(x, 4)]], datlist[[c(x, 5)]]) : 
  not enough 'x' observations

Comment: check the datlist variable to find items with zero rows. you have to exclude those items

Comment: I removed it using the following code: datlist<-datlist[sapply(datlist, nrow)>0]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91813/discussion-between-omar113-and-user).